# Non rails style format of XML response how to parse with ActiveResource correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prestashop, activeresource

Using Rails and ActiveResource i am getting non-rails style of XML response form third-party API. Object which i like to map is basically wrapped in prestahop element. What should i override to get rid of that element to map the object correctly?

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
    <id></id>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use custom formatter for your needs, something like this may be good solution.

```
class PrestaXMLFormatter
  include ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat

  def decode(xml)
    ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat.decode(xml)['prestashop']
  end
end

class Order < ActiveResource::Base
  self.format = PrestaXMLFormatter.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few external services where I have to talk non-rails style api. I'm using combination of [Savon](http://savonrb.com/) gem to make SOAP requests and parse SOAP responses, and [Roxml](https://github.com/Empact/roxml) gem to map actual XML into ruby objects.